# Android 5.0 translucent status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar, navigationbar

Going from https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar, I have had tons of different trials and errors on how to get status bar transparent, but not much luck.

I do not want navigation drawer, just a plane and simple activity with translucent status bar like they are showing on http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#imagery-best-practices

Here is my design

```
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> 
                <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
                <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
                     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
         <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>


    </style>
```

and code in java

```
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().getAttributes().flags &= (~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

I have gone through a lot of stackoverflow answers, including using ScrimInsetsFrameLayout, but nothing seem to achieve something as simple as following the exact rules

> You can also draw behind the status bar yourself. For example, if you want to show the status bar transparently over a photo, with a subtle dark gradient to ensure the white status icons are visible. To do so, set the android:statusBarColor attribute to @android:color/transparent and adjust the window flags as required. You can also use the Window.setStatusBarColor() method for animations or fading.  Note: The status bar should almost always have a clear delineation from the primary toolbar, except for cases where you show edge-to-edge rich imagery or media content behind these bars and when you use a gradient to ensure that the icons are still visible.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done using xml. Use framelayout so that you can add two or more imageviews into it.